# Doxygen enum not showing

Tags: objective-c, c, doxygen

Is it possible to have doxygen generate docs for an enum declared on one of my class headers? The enum for the property called 'scope' in [this link](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/interface_typhoon_definition.html#aa4df6569a008392075c9689a73d13729) is not showing as a documented type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your Doxyfile config and set the following:

```
SHOW_FILES = YES
```

. . and then simply add standard document-comments to the enum type.

It will now be [linked and documented](http://www.typhoonframework.org/docs/latest/api/group___definition.html).

Answer (score 5):

According to Doxygen manual [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/docblocks.html):

```
To document global objects (functions, typedefs, enum, macros, etc), you must document the file in which they are defined. In other words, there must at least be a

/*! \file */ 
or a
/** @file */ 
line in this file.
```

Here is an example:

```
/*! \file MyClass.h
    \brief A brief file description.

    More details
 */

/*! This is an enum */
enum Direction {
    kDirectionRight, /*!< this is right */
    kDirectionLeft,  /*!< this is left */
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Where does the \file directive go? Any chance of a little example, eps for an inline declared enum. (ie one declared at the top of the class header).

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful. However, it didn't work - adding the file tag and brief had no effect. . However, I modified my Doxyfile to include SHOW_FILES = YES, and then simply added a doc-tag to the enum.